# JavaScript reduce if-else loop

Tags: jquery

I get values from radio input fields and it works great!

My problem is, If I want to get values not from all fields but from two or three fields my script not work.

Here is my Example:

```
<script>

 /* View check boxes */
 var value_one = $('input[type=radio][name=value_one]:checked').data('value_one');
 var value_two = $('input[type=radio][name=value_two]:checked').data('value_zwei');
 var value_three = $('input[type=radio][name=value_three]:checked').data('value_three');
 var value_four = $('input[type=radio][name=value_four]:checked').data('value_four');

 if(value_one != ''){
  var result_one = ($(this).data("value_one") >= value_one == true);
 } else {
  var result_one = '';
 }

 if(value_two != ''){
  var result_two = ($(this).data("value_two") >= value_two == true);
 } else {
  var result_two = '';
 }

 if(value_three != ''){
  var result_three = ($(this).data("value_three") >= value_three == true);
 } else {
  var result_three = '';
 }

 if(value_four != ''){
  var result_four = ($(this).data("value_four") >= value_four == true);
 } else {
  var result_four = '';
 }

 /*
 Here begin my problem.
 */

 if(result_one && result_two && result_three && result_four){
 /*
  Do something
 */

 }
</script>
```

If i want to get values just from three fields Example just from result_one && result_two && result_three it not work. If I replace && with || it not work.

How can I set && just three time if i need it? I need an idea thank you!

Here my HTML-Code

```
<ul id="value_one">
 <li>value_one</li>
 <li><label for="minw01"><input type="radio" name="value_one" data-valu e_one="0" id="minw01"> egal</label></li>
 <li><label for="minw02"><input type="radio" name="value_one" data-value_one="5" id="minw02"> 5€</label></li>
 <li><label for="minw03"><input type="radio" name="value_one" data-value_one="10" id="minw03"> 10€</label></li>
 <li><label for="minw04"><input type="radio" name="value_one" data-value_one="15" id="minw04"> 15€</label></li>
 <li><label for="minw05"><input type="radio" name="value_one" data-value_one="25" id="minw05"> 25€</label></li>
 <li><label for="minw06"><input type="radio" name="value_one" data-value_one="26" id="minw06"> 26€ and more</label></li>
</ul>

<ul id="value_two">
 <li>value_two</li>
 <li><label for="lkost01"><input type="radio" name="value_two" data-value_two="1" id="lkost01"> egal</label></li>
  <li><label for="lkost02"><input type="radio" name="value_two" data-value_two="5" id="lkost02"> 5€</label></li>
  <li><label for="lkost03"><input type="radio" name="value_two" data-value_two="10" id="lkost03"> 10€</label></li>
  <li><label for="lkost04"><input type="radio" name="value_two" data-value_two="15" id="lkost04"> 15€</label></li>
  <li><label for="lkost05"><input type="radio" name="value_two" data-value_two="25" id="lkost05"> 25€</label></li>
  <li><label for="lkost06"><input type="radio" name="value_two" data-value_two="26" id="lkost06"> 26€ and more</label></li>
</ul>

<ul id="value_three">
 <li>value_three</li>
 <li><label for="essq01"><input type="radio" name="value_three" data-value_three="0" id="essq01"> egal</label></li>
 <li><label for="essq02"><input type="radio" name="value_three" data-value_three="1" id="essq02"> 1 Star</label></li>
 <li><label for="essq03"><input type="radio" name="value_three" data-value_three="2" id="essq03"> 2 Starts and more</label></li>
 <li><label for="essq04"><input type="radio" name="value_three" data-value_three="3" id="essq04"> 3 Starts and more</label></li>
 <li><label for="essq05"><input type="radio" name="value_three" data-value_three="4" id="essq05"> 4 Starts and more</label></li>
</ul>

<ul id="value_four">
 <li>value_four</li>
 <li><label for="portion01"><input type="radio" name="value_four" data-value_four="0" id="portion01"> egal</label></li>
 <li><label for="portion02"><input type="radio" name="value_four" data-value_four="1" id="portion02"> 1 Star</label></li>
 <li><label for="portion03"><input type="radio" name="value_four" data-value_four="2" id="portion03"> 2 Starts and more</label></li>
 <li><label for="portion04"><input type="radio" name="value_four" data-value_four="3" id="portion04"> 3 Starts and more</label></li>
 <li><label for="portion05"><input type="radio" name="value_four" data-value_four="4" id="portion05"> 4 Starts and more</label></li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Please include your html code

Comment: is there a reason why you're using radio buttons instead of check boxes?

Comment: yes it is a part of a selector filter.

Comment: @Juergen I've made an answer, but without you saying what you want to happen in `Do something` we cant say more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well your not that informative about what it is your code should do, but this should short it down.

```
$("input:radio").change(function() {

  if ($("input:radio:checked").length > 2) { // Now 3 radio's has to be selected
    $("input:radio:checked").each(function() {
      var id = $(this).closest("ul").attr("id");
      var data = $(this).data(id);

      console.log(data)
    })
  }
})
```

```js
$("input:radio").change(function() {

  if ($("input:radio:checked").length > 2) {
    $("input:radio:checked").each(function() {
      var id = $(this).closest("ul").attr("id");
      var data = $(this).data(id);

      console.log(data)
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="value_one">
  <li>value_one</li>
  <li><label for="minw01"><input type="radio" name="value_one" data-value_one="0" id="minw01"> egal</label></li>
  <li><label for="minw02"><input type="radio" name="value_one" data-value_one="5" id="minw02"> 5€</label></li>
  <li><label for="minw03"><input type="radio" name="value_one" data-value_one="10" id="minw03"> 10€</label></li>
  <li><label for="minw04"><input type="radio" name="value_one" data-value_one="15" id="minw04"> 15€</label></li>
  <li><label for="minw05"><input type="radio" name="value_one" data-value_one="25" id="minw05"> 25€</label></li>
  <li><label for="minw06"><input type="radio" name="value_one" data-value_one="26" id="minw06"> 26€ and more</label></li>
</ul>

<ul id="value_two">
  <li>value_two</li>
  <li><label for="lkost01"><input type="radio" name="value_two" data-value_two="1" id="lkost01"> egal</label></li>
  <li><label for="lkost02"><input type="radio" name="value_two" data-value_two="5" id="lkost02"> 5€</label></li>
  <li><label for="lkost03"><input type="radio" name="value_two" data-value_two="10" id="lkost03"> 10€</label></li>
  <li><label for="lkost04"><input type="radio" name="value_two" data-value_two="15" id="lkost04"> 15€</label></li>
  <li><label for="lkost05"><input type="radio" name="value_two" data-value_two="25" id="lkost05"> 25€</label></li>
  <li><label for="lkost06"><input type="radio" name="value_two" data-value_two="26" id="lkost06"> 26€ and more</label></li>
</ul>

<ul id="value_three">
  <li>value_three</li>
  <li><label for="essq01"><input type="radio" name="value_three" data-value_three="0" id="essq01"> egal</label></li>
  <li><label for="essq02"><input type="radio" name="value_three" data-value_three="1" id="essq02"> 1 Star</label></li>
  <li><label for="essq03"><input type="radio" name="value_three" data-value_three="2" id="essq03"> 2 Starts and more</label></li>
  <li><label for="essq04"><input type="radio" name="value_three" data-value_three="3" id="essq04"> 3 Starts and more</label></li>
  <li><label for="essq05"><input type="radio" name="value_three" data-value_three="4" id="essq05"> 4 Starts and more</label></li>
</ul>

<ul id="value_four">
  <li>value_four</li>
  <li><label for="portion01"><input type="radio" name="value_four" data-value_four="0" id="portion01"> egal</label></li>
  <li><label for="portion02"><input type="radio" name="value_four" data-value_four="1" id="portion02"> 1 Star</label></li>
  <li><label for="portion03"><input type="radio" name="value_four" data-value_four="2" id="portion03"> 2 Starts and more</label></li>
  <li><label for="portion04"><input type="radio" name="value_four" data-value_four="3" id="portion04"> 3 Starts and more</label></li>
  <li><label for="portion05"><input type="radio" name="value_four" data-value_four="4" id="portion05"> 4 Starts and more</label></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

here you can use for loop and use result also dynamic

```
for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
var val = $('input[type=radio][name=value_'+(i+1)']:checked').data('value_'+(i+1));
if(val != ''){
  var result = ($(this).data("value_"+(i+1)) >= val == true);
 } else {
   var result = '';
 }
}
```

Comment: It's a good idea, but it would not work, since hes `[name=value_'+(i+1)+']` would look like `[name=value_1]` and hes example is `[name=value_one]`

Comment: your correct @CarstenLøvboAndersen but in html itself we can change name like value_1

Answer (score 0):

you can use a var count with initial value as 0. Whenever the value is stored in var (for example result_one) you can increment its value. You can then use this count value to check the number of var containing non null value and perform operation on them (by using addition if statements).